# 'this' keyword within a function used on an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, this

See this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ambrwlsn90/pen/ELEmxw)

or the code snippet below

How can I get the button to log to the console when it is clicked? I am trying to learn how to use `this` in JavaScript. Thanks

```js
const button = document.getElementById("leet");

function LeetSpeaker (elem) {
  return {
    listenClick () {
      const self = this
      elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
        self.speakLeet()
      })
    },
    speakLeet() { console.log(`1337 15 4W350M3`) }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #b666d2;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<button id="leet" onclick="LeetSpeaker(button)">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't `this` in your code. Get rid of the inline javascript, execute LeetSpeaker(button).listenClick() in your js code and it works. To do it better, use an arrow function and then just `this.speakLeet()`

```js
const button = document.getElementById("leet");
LeetSpeaker(button).listenClick();

function LeetSpeaker(elem) {
  return {
    listenClick() {
      const self = this
      elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.speakLeet()
      })
    },
    speakLeet() {
      console.log(`1337 15 4W350M3`)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #b666d2;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<button id="leet">Click</button>
```

Or nicer, with an arrow function

```js
const button = document.getElementById("leet");
LeetSpeaker(button).listenClick();

function LeetSpeaker(elem) {
  return {
    listenClick() {
      elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.speakLeet()
      })
    },
    speakLeet() {
      console.log(`1337 15 4W350M3`)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: #b666d2;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<button id="leet">Click</button>
```